# Add condition to code to display text when item is not shown

Tags: html, css

Need some help with Embedded code that is on a Webflow site.

The code is pulling `CMS text` from the `CMS` to display but if there no text, I am trying to figure out a way to display text "unavailable".

Here is the current code in the Embed:

`< span data-brand= "CMS text"> </span >`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the span in css using `span[data-brand="CMS text"]`.

To check if span contains text use pseudo-elements `:empty`.

To add `content`. There is a CSS property with the same name. It works with the pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`

**For example:**

```
span[data-brand="CMS text"]:empty::after  {
    content: "unavailable";
}
```

Heres an example https://jsfiddle.net/nLw6z71t/2/